# SQL - Union count(*) from 3 different tables cause cartesian product

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, count, cartesian-product

I have 3 talbes: Posts, Pictures and Album. 
I need to count how many posts, pictures and albums per year were published.
Here the creation of the tables:

```
create table Posts
(
 PostID int primary key identity,
 Description varchar(30) not null,
 Date smalldatetime not null,
 UserWriterID int references Users(UserID)
)

create table Albums
(
 AlbumID int primary key identity,
 Name varchar(20) not null,
 Description varchar(30) not null,
 Date smalldatetime not null,
 AlbumOwnerID int references Users(UserID) 
)

create table Pictures
(
 PictureID int primary key identity,
 AlbumID int references Albums(AlbumID),
 Description varchar(30) not null,
 Date smalldatetime not null,
)
```

Some data samples from the tables:

**Pictures:**

```
PictureID | AlbumID | Desc | Date

    1    |   1   |   aa   | 2000-01-01 00:00:00

    2    |   1   |   bb   | 2011-08-31 15:24:00

    10   |   2   |   d    | 2010-07-17 12:35:00
```

**Albums:**

```
AlbumID | Name |    Desc    |    Date     |      AlbumOwnerID

1   |   My album | my new album |  2000-01-01 00:00:00 |    2

2   |   Belgium trip    | trip in Belgium |  2005-07-08 00:00:00 |  2

9   |    Work   | Work and I  | 2011-07-08 00:00:00  |  11
```

**Posts:**

```
PostID  | Desc | Date | UserWriterID

1  |  Feeling good |    2013-09-10 07:44:00 |  2

2   |  FUN FUN FUN |  2015-12-21 09:45:00  |    8

3   |   Whats up?   | 2014-01-18 12:54:00 |     7
```

Then I inserted data.

Now, I writen 3 queries to get per each table the count per year.

```
create view PostPerYear as
select YEAR(Date) as Year , count(PostID) as Posts
from Posts
group by YEAR(Date)
go 

create view AlbumsPerYear as
select YEAR(Date) as Year , count(AlbumID) as Albums
from Albums 
group by YEAR(Date)
go

create view PicturesPerYear as
select YEAR(Date) as Year , count(PictureID) as Pictures
from Pictures
group by YEAR(Date)
go
```

But, I need a query that show all the results above **TOGETHER**.
For example:

Year | Posts Count | Albums Count | Pictures Count

2013 | 3           | 4            | 1

2005 | 13          |23            | 5

When I tried I've got cartesian product like:

```
select (p.Year) , (p.Posts) ,  (a.Albums) , (pic.Pictures)
from PostPerYear p ,AlbumsPerYear a ,PicturesPerYear pic
group by p.Year, p.Posts , a.Albums , pic.Pictures
```

The result is:
    Year|    Posts | Albums | Pictures

```
2013    9   1   1

2013    9   1   2

2013    9   1   3

2013    9   1   4

2013    9   1   5

2013    9   1   6

2013    9   1   11

2013    9   2   1

2013    9   2   2

2013    9   2   6

2013    9   2   11

2014    10  1   1

2014    10  1   2

2014    10  1   3

2014    10  1   4

2014    10  1   5

2014    10  1   6

And Continued....
------------------------------
------------------------------
```

What is the answer PLEASE?

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, if your tables are large your current queries will be slow due to ignoring any index on `date`.  If you have something like a Calendar Table, you should be able to turn this into a range query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying multiple tables in the `FROM` clause is equivalent to doing a `CROSS JOIN`. You can use `UNION ALL` to solve that problem.

```
WITH summary(year, posts, albums, pictures) AS (        
    SELECT year, posts, 0, 0 FROM PostsPerYear        
    UNION ALL        
    SELECT year, 0, albums, 0 FROM AlbumsPerYear        
    UNION ALL        
    SELECT year, 0, 0, pictures FROM PicturesPerYear        
)        
SELECT year,        
       sum(posts)    AS posts,        
       sum(albums)   AS albums,        
       sum(pictures) AS pictures        
FROM summary        
GROUP BY year;
```

Comment: It returns with zero's like this:
2000 0 0 2

2001 0 0 4
2002 0 0 4
2003 0 0 2
2005 0 0 6
2006 0 0 1
2007 0 0 4
2008 0 0 2
2009 0 0 6
2010 0 0 7
2011 0 0 13
2012 0 0 5
2013 0 0 9
2014 0 0 10
2015 0 0 8
2016 0 0 8
2017 0 0 12
2018 0 0 8
2019 0 0 7

Comment: Could you provide the data from the views?

Comment: Please look at my fiddle and see if the output is right.

Comment: It works! you right!
I copied not correctly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First the simplified DDL and some sample data:

```
create table Posts
(
 PostID int primary key identity,
 Date smalldatetime not null
)

create table Albums
(
 AlbumID int primary key identity,
 Date smalldatetime not null
)

create table Pictures
(
 PictureID int primary key identity,
 Date smalldatetime not null,
)




create view PostPerYear as
select YEAR(Date) as Year , count(PostID) as Posts
from Posts
group by YEAR(Date)
go 

create view AlbumsPerYear as
select YEAR(Date) as Year , count(AlbumID) as Albums
from Albums 
group by YEAR(Date)
go

create view PicturesPerYear as
select YEAR(Date) as Year , count(PictureID) as Pictures
from Pictures
group by YEAR(Date)
go


insert posts values('20130101'), ('20140202')
insert albums values('20130101'), ('20140202'), ('20140202')
insert pictures values('20130101'), ('20130101'), ('20140202')
go
```

Now, use outer joins (I'd recommend to use ANSI join syntax):

```
select coalesce(p.Year, a.year, pic.year) as year, p.Posts, a.Albums, pic.Pictures
from PostPerYear p 
full outer join AlbumsPerYear a on p.year = a.year
full outer join PicturesPerYear pic on p.year = pic.year
```

Returns this:

```
Year    Posts   Albums  Pictures
2013    1   1   2
2014    1   2   1
```

Comment: It's return the same but with nulls.
Year | Posts | Albums | Pictures
NULL NULL 1 NULL
NULL NULL 2 NULL
NULL NULL 1 NULL
NULL NULL 2 NULL
NULL NULL 1 NULL
NULL NULL 1 NULL
NULL NULL 1 NULL
NULL NULL 2 NULL
2013 9 NULL NULL
2016 8 NULL NULL
2019 7 NULL NULL
2014 10 NULL NULL
2017 12 NULL NULL
2018 8 NULL NULL
2015 8 NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL 6
NULL NULL NULL 2
NULL NULL NULL 3
NULL NULL NULL 3
NULL NULL NULL 2
NULL NULL NULL 4
NULL NULL NULL 1
NULL NULL NULL 2
NULL NULL NULL 11
NULL NULL NULL 1
NULL NULL NULL 5
NULL NULL NULL 5

Comment: It doesn't, I've included a full sample to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but this is what I've got..
Each view returns correctly.
Your query returns with NULL's.
Here's:
[link]http://oi58.tinypic.com/2u70t3a.jpg

Comment: Should've used `coalesce` on year. If still not working OK, pls give me some sample data.

Comment: It's return only the count of Posts.
The others is null.
The only years that appear is 2013 to 2019 that it's the years of the posts, not for the albums & pictures

Comment: Pls add some sample data to your post or create a fiddle.

Comment: Attached to the post above

Comment: @Dean - You also need to use `COALESCE` on the count columns.